# Is a suggested edit thrown out of the Queue when it is ignored/skipped?

Tags: support, help

What happens when a suggested edit is ignored/skipped?

Is it thrown out of the queue and how much time does it take to get out of the suggested edit Queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, suggested edit is not thrown out of the review queue when someone chooses to "skip" that review. That suggested edit remains in the queue till other reviewers decide to take an action on it. The "skip" button is just for the current reviewer, if you're unsure about the edit and you want to move on to the next review item without taking action on the current one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. what if nobody reviewed it in 1 or 2 hours? is it automatically removed from the queue then?

Comment: @Starken No. Why would it be?

Comment: @Starkeen: As far as I know, only SO's Help and Improvement queue has any provision for skips eventually removing items from the queue. It takes a fair number to do that, though; Suggested Edits can stay in the system as long as needed, although the longest I've seen is maybe 12 hours.